# how to sort a table by default descending order cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, cakephp

I would like to know how to sort a table header only in that page without sorting the whole table.is this possible in cakephp?

This is my view:

```
<?php
                echo   $url = $this->Paginator->sort('ID', 'id',array('direction' => 'desc'));
                $arrow = getArrow($url);
              ?>
```

This is my controller:

```
$this->paginate = Set::merge($this->paginate, array('OrderFinalized' => array(


                        'limit'=>4,
                        'conditions' => $condition_ary,
                                'joins' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'table' => 'order_entry_headers',
                                        'alias' => 'OrderEntryHeaders2',
                                        'type' => 'inner',
                                        'foreignKey' => false,
                                        'conditions' => array('OrderEntryHeaders2.id = OrderFinalized.order_entry_headers_id'),

                                            'order' => array(
'OrderEntryHeaders2.id'=> 'desc'
 )
                ),

$result = $this->OrderEntryHeader->query("SELECT (value+1) as val FROM order_entries_seq ORDER BY OrderEntryHeader.id desc ");
```

Comment: You are not describing anything about pagination - assuming what you mean [this](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html).

Comment: well during page load default should be descending. i already get exactly something like this.but what i want is when sorting must only sort whats in the page..in that example when sorting happens it sort everything in that data table

Comment: `sorting must only sort whats in the page..in that example when sorting happens it sort everything in that data table` What difference/distinction do you wish to make? **Please edit _your first_ question to clarify**. You've asked this question 3 times now...